# Aligning an image next to a table row

Tags: html, css

I want to display image next to each row in a table using Html and CSS.
Something like this image:

[image]

Images will be placed at the red cross position: on right side of each row and not created within extra column.

What would be the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the :last-child combined with the :after pseudo.

```css
tr td:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: url("http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </thead>
  <tb>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tb>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another column with a blank table header should do it.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>  </th> -- This is the blank space 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>Image goes here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can always style it up to appear like it is not apart of the table.